How to edit toc.dat file without compromising binary?
I am looking for a way to properly edit a toc.dat file generated by a pg_dump.
The idea is to rename the schema's name before the data import with pg_restore.
pg_dump -j 2 --host localhost -p 5433 -Fd --dbname dbname --username username -n schema -f directory

So far I have tried to do so with a perl or sed command:
sed -i.bak -e 's/schema\./schema_new\./g' -e 's/schema;/schema_new;/g' toc.dat

However, I got a segmentation fault error:
[1]    22867 segmentation fault  pg_restore --no-owner --no-acl -h localhost -p 5433 -U username -d  -n

When I try to pg_restore:
pg_restore --no-owner --no-acl -h localhost -p 5433 -U username -d other_dbname -n schema_new -v directory

I know that I could bypass this issue with a textual pg_dump file but if possible I would like to stick with the toc.dat method for memory storage optimization.
PostGres version: 14.10
pg_dump/pg_restore version: 15.6

Seems making this a 'regular' question lost all the comments from the staging post. My comment at this point is your pg_restore command and segmentation fault do not match the command you say you are running something like: pg_restore -h localhost -p 5433 -d dbname -U username -v -L toc.txt.  If you want an answer all the parts need to match. Also you will need to update to indicate you are now running sed against toc.txt not toc.dat.

The command pg_restore -h localhost -p 5433 -d dbname -U username -v -L toc.txt does not work as it is, you can try it. It expects a folder in last argument. If a toc.datfile is not in that folder the command returns error: directory "." does not appear to be a valid archive ("toc.dat" does not exist). For some reason toc.txtis ignored.

Don't get rid of toc.dat, leave it in the directory. Create the toc.txt in the same directory and modify it. The simple way to run the restore is in that directory do something like: pg_restore -d toc_test -U postgres -L toc.txt . Note the . at the end.  Otherwise you will have to add the correct path to both toc.txt  and the archive directory like: pg_restore -d toc_test -U postgres -L /some/path/toc.txt  /archive_path/

Yes I have tried this command pg_restore -d toc_test -U postgres -L toc.txt . but it restores initial schema (not schema_new) eventhough it is renamed as schema_new in toc.txt file. pg_restore seems to ignore toc.txt file and restore with toc.dat one.

More likely your sed modification of toc.txt did not do what you thought it did. I just ran a quick test here and it did not modify the file.

For toc.txtedition you have to use this command sed -i.bak -e  's/ schema / schema_new /g' toc.txt as this file has a different syntax as toc.dat. However it does not solve the issue.

I did not think this through.  When you modify the schema in toc.txt that modifies the schema name, however when you feed it back to pg_restore with -L it uses the TOC line number to match up with entries in toc.dat and restores the definition as found in toc.dat. The only way I can think of getting around this is to turn the directory format into plain text using pg_restore -f plain_txt.sql . in the directory. Then you would be working directly on what will be run when you do psql -f plain,txt.sql.

Hence my sentence in my initial question : "I know that I could bypass this issue with a textual pg_dump file but if possible I would like to stick with the toc.dat method for memory storage optimization.". So far it confirms that it is not possible to do it with a toc.dat archive.

Does not look like it, doing text replacement in a binary file is bound to lead to all sorts of issues.
